# TRANSACTION in java + sqlite3

Tags: java, transactions, sqlite

How can I make transaction in java+sqlite3 i check google already.I want to make it to be rollback statement so if somewhere in statement goes wrong all statement go  to "space" and the DB got rollback to moment before start transaction.

Something like that here [Roolback-stmt](http://sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#rollback-stmt) I hope my question is understandable. So remember that English is not my native language. Here is part of code that I want to make to be a statement:

```
ArrayList <String> al = new ArrayList <String> ();
try {
    // transaction begin;
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select _id, godziny_id from tblZmiany where harmonogram_id = " + h_id + " order by pracownik_id, Dzien");
    while (rs.next()) {
        al.add("insert into tblWykonanie (Zmiana_id, Godziny_id) values ('" + rs.getLong(1) + "', " + rs.getInt(2) + ");");
    }
    for (String s : al)
        if (stat.executeUpdate(s) < 1) {
            // Jeśli insert nie wstawił kolejnego rekordu
            //rollback;
            error_code = "Wystąpił problem podczas zatwierdzania harmonogramu.";
            return false;
        }
        // commit;           
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    return false;
} catch (Exception e) {
    error_code = e.getMessage();
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this one of two ways, at the connection level or via *batch statements*.

At the connection level:

```
final boolean oldAutoCommit = stat.getConnection().getAutoCommit();
stat.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);

try {
    // Your update and insert code here
} catch(Exception e) {
    stat.getConnection().rollback();
} finally {
    stat.getConnection().commit();
    stat.getConnection().setAutoCommit(oldAutoCommit);
}
```

Error handling has been omitted from the pseudocode, but you get the general idea. You may wish to avoid messing around with the connection, and to instead use *batch statements*:

```
for(String query: queries) {
    stat.addBatch(query);
}

try {
    stat.executeBatch();
} catch(Exception e) {
    // ...
}
```

Which is alot cleaner. Remember that you can always check wether your DB/Driver supports batched transaction via `DatabaseMetaData.supportsBatchUpdates()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use a JDBC driver like [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) which supports transactions.

Comment: I use sqlitejdbc-v056 from Zentus

Comment: The Zentus driver is somewhat outdated.

Comment: I'm not interested is it outdated or no, because until now this work for me perfect I need to now how to make Transaction here in this samplecode.